# Solenoid driver does not work reliably

Tags: solenoid

I have to drive a solenoid with the following schematic:

[image]

It works great but sometimes the MIC5020 or the input pin of microcontroller fails and can therefore no longer be pulled high, but I can't quite understand why.

VSOL: 48V DC.

VSOL_MEAS: measurement pin to see if 48v is present.

SOL_SENS: measurement pin to see if solenoid is present.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know, but generally a 100 ohms or so is used in the gate wire due to its capacitance. Are your sense inputs backwards? I would expect SENSE - to be connected to GND. You might [edit] to explain what "input pin of microcontroller fails" means. It doesn't switch? Sometimes or until the power is reset? It destroys the microcontroller? Don't be vague!

Comment: with "input pin of microcontroller fails" i mean that the pin of the microcontroller doesn't work anymore and can't be switched on. also the sense pin is connected to ground

Comment: Sorry, the shrunk image on my screen dropped the vertical line on the SENSE +. It is correct. You haven't made it clear whether or not the microcontroller is damaged or works again on power cycle. Clarify in the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete answer, microcontroller gets damaged even after reset icant pull the pin high.
thanks for the replies!

Comment: Where does VSOL come from?  A battery, or a powersupply?  How long are the connections from VSOL to the source?

Comment: VSOL is my +48v power supply  and the connections are not longer then 60mm

Comment: @Transistor, I thought the same at first but the MIC5020 is a FET driver for direct gate driving, as per its datasheet.

Comment: So if I put a 100Ohm resistor between the MIC5020 and the microcontroller pin, would the microcontroller stay safe?

Comment: What's your layout and decoupling situation?

Comment: @winny currently there is no decoupling for the mic5020 and path between mic5020 and mosfet is as short as it can be (is right below it

)

Comment: The datasheet says to use a minimum of 10 microfarads on VDD of the MIC2050. I expect that's where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Why? You have to decouple with >10uF according to the datasheet. What's your layout situation? Same questions for the MCU too. What do you think prevents D6 from pumping your VSOL without decoupling?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with pumping VSOL? and the microcontroller gets a steady 3.3V source wich is decoupled

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It will be clamped by the diode assuming it's fast enough and placement. How is your playment and layout? You are avoiding answeing it. 3.3 V is decoupled where? Show layout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D6 is supposed to dump the kickback from the solenoid to the VSOL line.

VSOL then has to dump that current somewhere.  If it doesn't, then VSOL will rise.

You are using 48V to power the MIC2050 and the solenoid.  It wouldn't take much for the kickback from the solenoid to raise VSOL above the rated 50V (or even the absolute maximum of 55V.)

If the MIC2050 fails, then the kickback from the solenoid could get to your microprocessor GPIO pin.  That would destroy it.

Many powersupplies can't absorb the kickback.  They can regulate their own output, but don't have any way to handle current coming in on the output.

The capacitor specified in the [MIC2050 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/mic5020.pdf) would absorb some (or all) of the kickback.  The datasheet also shows the MIC2050 being powered from a separate supply than the solenoid.  That would keep all spikes away from the MIC2050.

1. Add decoupling capacitors as directed in the datasheet.
2. Consider a regulator between VSOL and VDD on the MIC2050.

Comment: The capcaitor indeed did the trick and thanks for your time! is it also a good way of thinking to provide an extra resistance between µC pin and MIC5020? or is this not necessary?

Comment: A resistor alone would not be a good idea.  Better to make certain that you won't get voltage spikes than to try and dampen them.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help it is very much appreciated!